# Grunt hangs when executed from a node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to wrap the execution of a grunt task inside another node script (for build simple integrations) and am having a problem getting all the tasks to run. Here's my very simple test script:

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var g = require('grunt');
g.tasks();
```

And here is the output:

```
-> % node test.js
    Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
    >> 50 files lint free.

    Running "clean:server" (clean) task

    Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task
```

The process is stuck on the concurrent tasks, and pegs the cpu at 100%. It seems to do this for any concurrent task. If it skips the :test task it fails at another one later on with compass and a few other things.

test.js is in the same directory as my Gruntfile.js. If I run just 'grunt' it complete the process fine.

Gruntfile.js: Pretty stock yeoman Gruntfile

```
// Generated on 2013-07-29 using generator-angular 0.3.1
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT});
var mountFolder = function(connect, dir) {
return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function(grunt) {
// load all grunt tasks
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

try {
    yeomanConfig.app = require('./bower.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
} catch (e) {
}

grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    open: {
        server: {
            url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/bootstrap.min.js'
        ]
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false
        },
        dist: {},
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
     dist: {}
     },*/
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/**/*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        // By default, your `index.html` <!-- Usemin Block --> will take care of
        // minification. This option is pre-configured if you do not wish to use
        // Usemin blocks.
        // dist: {
        //   files: {
        //     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //       '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //       '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //     ]
        //   }
        // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                 // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                 //collapseWhitespace: true,
                 collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                 removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                 removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                 useShortDoctype: true,
                 removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                 removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: ['*.html', 'views/**/*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
        }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'bower_components/**/*',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
                        'styles/fonts/*',
                        'fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: [
                        'generated/*'
                    ]
                }]
        }
    },
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server'
        ],
        test: [
            'compass'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass:dist',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin',
            'htmlmin'
        ]
    },
    karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        },
    cdnify: {
        dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
    },
    ngmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
                }]
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function(target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'concat',
    'copy',
    'ngmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

**Workaround:** If I move the tasks in the concurrent groupings to be listed separately under the registerTask the process works fine.

Comment: Can you please post the content of your Gruntfile.js.

Comment: Sure, see edited post. It's a pretty standard yeoman generated Gruntfile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server hangs on Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464444/server-hangs-on-running-concurrentserver-concurrent-task)